# Can my implementation of filter be improved?

Tags: haskell, fold

An exercise in Haskell from First Principles says to implement `filter` using `foldr` and this is what I came up with but it feels and looks clunky. Is there a more natural way to implement it with a `foldr`?

```
import Data.Bool
myFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myFilter f = foldr (\x -> bool (++ []) ((:) x) (f x)) []
```

Comment: `(++[])` is just `id`.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone would find `((:) x)` less clunky than `(x :)`.

Comment: @chepner I changed that one a few seconds ago lol.

Comment: @chepner what do you mean? (⊢ never (is clunky (notation 'prefix)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would *only* use `bool` if it let me get rid of the lambda expression simply, by composing a call to `bool` with the predicate `p`: `bool iffalse iftrue . p`. However, `p` isn't the only function that needs to be called on a list element; `(:)` does as well. You *could* use the `Applicative` instance for functions, to write

```
myfilter p = foldr (bool id . (:) <*> p) []  -- yuck
```

but in this case I would just use a plain `if` expression, inside the lambda expression:

```
myfilter p = foldr (\x -> if p x then (x:) else id) []  -- much clearer!
```

---

Note that when specialized to functions, the `Applicative`'s `(<*>)` operator is defined as `f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)`. I leave it as an exercise to use that definition to transform `bool id . (:) <*> p` into
`\x -> bool id (x:) (p x)`.

Comment: That applicative code is indeed quite obfuscated. I also greatly prefer the plain code below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Applicative` instance of `(->) a` to make the lambda cleaner. But, if you want to use `foldr`, I don't think there's any substantial change you can effect:

```
myFilter f = foldr (bool id <$> (:) <*> f) []
```

`bool id <$> (:) <*> f` means `\x -> bool id ((:) x) (f x)`. `bool id` has type `([a] -> [a]) -> Bool -> ([a] -> [a])`. `(:)` has type `a -> [a] -> [a]`, and `f` has type `a -> Bool`. When `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` are used in this way, you can think of it as pretending that `(:)` and `f` don't have an `a` argument, making them `[a] -> [a]` and `Bool`, respectively, applying them to `bool id` to get a `[a] -> [a]`, and then ending the lie by reintroducing the `a` argument, making a `a -> [a] -> [a]`. The operators are in charge of threading that `a` around, so you don't need a lambda abstraction.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Applicative` yet but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than merely searching for a more elegant implementation, it would might help you more to learn an elegant process of searching for an implementation. This should make it simpler to find elegant solutions.

For any function `h` on lists we have that,

```
h = foldr f e
```

if and only if

```
h [] = e
h (x:xs) = f x (h xs)
```

In this case your `h` is `filter p` for some boolean function `p` that selects which elements to keep. Implementing `filter p` as a "simple" recursive function is not too hard.

```
filter p [] = []
filter p (x:xs) = if p x then x : (filter p xs) else (filter p xs)
```

The 1st line implies `e = []`. The 2nd line needs to be written in the form `f x (filter p xs)` to match the equation of `h` above, in order for us to deduce which `f` to plug in  the `foldr`. To do that we just abstract over those two expressions.

```
filter p [] = []
filter p (x:xs) = (\x ys -> if p x then x : ys else ys) x (filter p xs)
```

So we have found that,

```
e = [] 
f x ys = if p x then x: ys else ys
```

It therefore follows,

```
filter p = foldr (\y ys -> if p y then y : ys else ys) []
```

To learn more about this method of working with `foldr` I recommend reading 
["A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold"](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf) by Graham Hutton.

**Some added notes:**

In case this seems overly complicated, note that while the principles above can be used in this "semi rigorous" fashion via algebraic manipulation, they can and should also be used to guide your intuition and aid you in informal development.

The equation for `h (x:xs) = f x (h xs)` sheds some clarity on how to find `f`. In the case where `h` is the filtering function you want an `f` which combines the element `x` with a tail that has already been filtered. If you really understand this it should be easy to arrive at,

```
f x ys = if p x then x : ys else ys
```

Comment: I also sensed some Richard Bird in there, esp. at the start, from his "theory of lists"... :) is it so?

Comment: Possibly, since my very first book on Haskell was his classic "Introduction to Functional Programming using Haskell", but never read that particular paper to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

```
myFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myFilter f = foldMap (\x -> [x | f x])

> myFilter even [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

See, I switched it on you, with `foldMap`.

Well, with `foldr` it is `foldr (\x -> ([x | f x] ++)) []`.